# How Do I Test If The First Letter Of A String Is "A" in C++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I want to see if the first letter of the string that the user entered is *a*. How can I do that with only iostream? Or if I can't which do I have to include? 
I have:

cin >> String

And here I need something to tell me if the first letter of the String is A.

Comment: `str[0] == 'A'` ?

Comment: Post some code that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Got code to show? Because this question seems too simple.

Comment: Do you mean "std::cin"  by "user entered"? It can be as simple as std::cin >> str; and as suggested by @George if (str[0] == 'A')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .at() function of the string

```
        string a = "ATest";
        if(a.at(0) == 'A')
            cout<<"True";
        else cout<<"False";
```

Comment: Note to implementors: Don't forget to deal with the exception thrown if the string is empty.

Comment: Why `at(0)` instead of simply using `a[0]`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ they are interchangeable but I believe .at() is preferred since it would throw an error if you are out of range. While using a[] will not

Comment: @MrBuggy That error could be easily avoided by checking for `empty()` first. That's exactly why I'm asking, `at()` introduces unnecessary overhead. And no, it's usually not preferred.

Comment: Actually the better way would be, if there is a regular possibility of an empty string, to pretest and skip the exception overhead. If it should be impossible to have an empty string, then finding one is truly exceptional behaviour and should be treated as such.